# I am getting this error when I press the details action link of an item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Every time I click on details for an item it gives me the error and the id is equal to 0, but if change the id number to anything greater than 1 within the number of items I have it runs properly
Here is my method

```
public PhoneModel GetPhone(int id)
{
    using(var context = new ElectronicsDataBaseEntities())
    {
         var result = context.Phone
              .Where(x => x.Id == id)
              .Select(x => new PhoneModel()
              {
                  Name = x.Name,
                  Phonemodel = x.Model,
                  DateReleased = x.DateReleased,
                  Desicription = x.Desicription
               })
               .FirstOrDefault();

                return result;
      }
}
```

and this my action method in the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) 
{
    var result = repository.GetPhone(id);
    return View(result);
}
```

[Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcLP4.png)
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhOmd.png)

[idex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEong.png)
[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOCug.png)

Comment: Probably your method `repository.GetPhone(id)` is returning null

Comment: Pls post your index view pls

Answer (score 0):

Add Id to  your query, and check if your query has find something. Since your url shows that Id=0,  you need to fix your index view. It must be the same story. You will have to add Id to select query for the index view.

```
.....
.Select(x => new PhoneModel()
                    {
                        Id=x.Id,

                        Name = x.Name,
                        Phonemodel = x.Model,
                        DateReleased = x.DateReleased,
                        Desicription = x.Desicription
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
....
```

Update

Try to use this code for your edit action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Phone", new { id=item.Id })
```

and fix etting all records method

```
public List<PhoneModel> GetAllPhones()
{  

 using(var context = new ElectronicsDataBaseEntities()) 
 { 
   var result = context.Phone .Select(x => new PhoneModel() 
  { 
   Id=x.Id,

  Name = x.Name, 
  Phonemodel = x.Model, 
  DateReleased = x.DateReleased, 
  Desicription = x.Desicription 
  }).ToList(); 

 return result; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: #Thanks. I have added the Id=x.Id but it's still coming up with that, am not really sure what you  meant I must fix my index, but I deleted it and redid but it's still the same

Comment: Can you post your index view.  pls. Index table  link is not working properly. It maybe the same story.

Comment: they have now closed the question so I don't think you will be able to see the index code that I added. but here my links from the index         <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>

Comment: @adamp You have to post query is used for Index model

Comment: Getting all records method    public List<PhoneModel> GetAllPhones()
        {
            using(var context = new ElectronicsDataBaseEntities())
            {
                var result = context.Phone
                    .Select(x => new PhoneModel()
                    {
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Phonemodel = x.Model,
                        DateReleased = x.DateReleased,
                        Desicription = x.Desicription
                    }).ToList();

                return result;
            }
        }

Comment: action method    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = repository.GetAllPhones();
            return View(result);
        }